# Trying to Parse a JSON using Python but having issues

Tags: python, json, parsing, python-requests

I usually use Powershell and have parsed JSONs from HTTP requests, successfully, before.  I am now using Python and using the 'Requests' library.  I have successfully got the JSON from the API.  Here is the format it came through in (I removed some information and other fields).:

```
{'content': [
    {
    'ContactCompany': Star,
    'ContactEmail': test@company.star,
    'ContactPhoneNumber': 123-456-7894, 
     'assignedGroup': 'TR_Hospital', 
     'assignedGroupId': 'SGP000000132297',  
     'serviceClass': None, 'serviceReconId': None
     }
            ]
}
```

I'm having trouble getting the values inside of the 'content.' With my Powershell experience in the past, I've tried:

`tickets_json = requests.get(request_url, headers=api_header).json()`

`Tickets_Info = tickets_json.content`

`for tickets in tickets_info:`
`tickets.assignedGroup`

How do I parse the JSON to get the information inside of 'Content' in Python?

Comment: `Tickets_Info` is a `dict`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tickets_json = requests.get(request_url, headers=api_header).json()

tickets_info = tickets_json['content']

for tickets in tickets_info: 
    print(tickets['assignedGroup'])
```

Comment: It's always that one simple piece of syntax that is missing to make it work :)  The second row is exactly what I was missing!